# Command for stopping program after some cutoff ram usage

Tags: ram, memory-usage

I sometimes use some programs that use too much RAM and owing to RAM being filled up completely, my system crashes.

Is there any command to make ubuntu automatically stop the execution of some particular process after using certain amount of RAM?

Comment: Perhaps a while block to check current RAM usage and stop process if target is exceeded would suffice?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the bash 'while loop' to achieve this. Here is a simple script I wired up, that will exit if you run out of memory:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x
set -e

state=$(sed -E 's/^[[:space:]]*([[:digit:]]*).*/\1/' <<< $(egrep --color 'MemFree' /proc/meminfo | cut -d" " -f2-))
check="2000000"

while [ "$state" -gt "$check" ]
do
    echo "Lots of memory"

done

echo "Out of memory"
exit 1
```

The script gets it's information from the '/proc/meminfo' file and checks for the free memory left. But of course modify to your needs.

Information:

- `set -x`: used to debug the script.
- `set -e`: stop script on first error.
- `state=$(sed -E 's/^[[:space:]]*([[:digit:]]*).*/\1/' <<< $(egrep --color 'MemFree' /proc/meminfo | cut -d" " -f2-))`: get the free memory from '/proc/meminfo' file and format it for use.